# Output for the following C code is confusing me

Tags: c

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    c=getchar();
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        int x;
        x=(c!=EOF);
        printf("%d",x);
        putchar(c);
        c=getchar();
    }
}
```

Output (When I enter `A`):

```
A
1A1
```

Why is it not `1A` only. Why is it repeating `1`.Like first the program will take the value of c from getchar. Then it will go inside the loop. When condition will be true it will print the value of x and then value of c. Then again it should ask me for an input. Instead it is displaying another 1 then asking for the input. Kindly help.

Comment: not reproducible: https://ideone.com/UzHvTo

Comment: You probably typed A and then RETURN, so you get 1 then A then 1 then \n.

Comment: Instead of writing weird code that makes it hard to understand what's going on, write code that makes it easy. Namely `printf("%d\n", c)`. After which you'll see something like 65 13 and then you can probably answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 9):

It is because you entered `A` and `<enter>`. The `<enter>` produces the second `1`.

You can press `CTRL` + `D` on unix or `CTRL` + `Z` on Windows to close the stdin of the program instead of pressing `<enter>`. This will give you the expected output.

With the `<enter>`: https://ideone.com/lWJ3Xz

and without: https://ideone.com/QsXiYz

Comment: my wrong, thanks +1

Comment: On a Unix TTY in canonical input mode, Ctrl+D (`VEOF`) only causes EOF when the line buffer is empty. So you'd need to type it twice: `1` `Ctrl+D` `Ctrl+D` for the desired effect. The first Ctrl+D makes the incomplete line available to the waiting program. The second Ctrl+D makes a subsequent read on the now empty buffer return 0, which is seen as EOF.

Answer (score 3):

a minimum debug effort and you will know yourself.

`printf("FEOF=%d, C=0x%x\n",x,c);`